# Audio stops playing when back button is pressed

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, avplayer, avaudioplayer

In my sample project, when czsm bar button item is tapped the audio should continue playing instead of stopping.

Here is the code that lists the songs:

```
import Firebase
import Nuke

struct getSongIndex {
    static var selectedIndex      : NSInteger!
    static var selectedUrl        : String?
    static var selectedArtistName : String?
    static var selectedSongName   : String?
    static var arrayurl        = [String]()
    static var arraysongname   = [String]()
    static var arrayartistname = [String]()
    static var arrayimageurl   = [String]()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: 
  IndexPath) 
{    
    getSongIndex.selectedIndex      = indexPath.row
    print("selected index is:::",getSongIndex.selectedIndex)
    getSongIndex.selectedUrl        = musicList[indexPath.row].songUrl
    getSongIndex.selectedSongName   = musicList[indexPath.row].songName
    getSongIndex.selectedArtistName = musicList[indexPath.row].artistName


    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc         = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: 
    "ViewController") as! MainViewController

    self.navigationController!.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

Here is the code for playing songs, when a song is selected it navigates to mainviewcontroller to play it.

```
var musiclist = [MusicList]()
var player     : AVPlayer?
var playerItem : AVPlayerItem?
var playButton : UIButton?
var isClicked      : Bool = false
var songPostion    : NSInteger = 0
var someValue      : NSInteger = 0
var getsongPostion : NSInteger = 0
var getSongUrl     : String?
var getArtistName  : String?
var getSongName    : String?
func playFunc(){
    if getSongIndex.arrayurl.count > getsongPostion{
        centerButton.isHidden = true
        playButton?.isHidden = true
        pauseButton.isHidden = false

        let url = URL(string: getSongIndex.arrayurl[getsongPostion])

        let playerItem:AVPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url!)
        player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
        if player?.rate == 0
        {
            player!.play()

        } else {
            player!.pause()

        }

        songName.text   = getSongIndex.arraysongname[getsongPostion]
        artistName.text = getSongIndex.arrayartistname[getsongPostion]

    }
}
```

However, when I press the czsm button to go back to the list view controller, the audio should continue playing.

Comment: Where is `playFunc()` actually called?

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth playbtn, previousbtn, nextbtn and viewWillAppear in mainviewcontroller.

Comment: This can happen if your player object is going out of scope and getting disposed of.  How is the navigation between the two view controllers handled i.e. when you navigate back to the list view controller is the main view controller being discarded.

Answer (score 0):

var player     : AVPlayer?

Declared player outside class (mainviewcontroller)

now its working fine